# ExUnit mocks get mixed up in their concurrency (async: false not working?)

Tags: elixir, meck

While executing `ExUnit.start`, in each case, I prepare mocks by `meck` like bellow

```rb
defmodule MyModule.FooTest do
    use ExUnit.Case, async: false # explicitly sync
    import :meck

    alias MyModule.Foo
    alias MyModule.Baz # to be mocked

    test "call_baz" do
        expect(Baz, :some_async_method, [
            {[], :meck.val(Task.async(fn -> %{"name" => "otiai10"} end)},
        ])

        assert Foo.call_baz() == %{"name" => "otiai10"}
    end
end
```

But it returns `{"name" => "otiai200"}` , because `Baz.some_async_method` is mocked by **another test** with returning `{"name" => "otiai200"}`.

It is certainly the response of what mocked in another test cases. (They are also given `async: false` option in their `use` statement)

What is the problem, `async: false` option doesn't work? or is mocking `Task.async` not recommended? Or do I do any basic mistakes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meck requires explicit unloading of mocks. Therefore, it is possible that another test running in parallel will update the expectation while you are running this test. Try adding `:meck.unload(Baz)` in the teardown to each test using the mock.

I'm not familiar with how Elixir decides to run it's test suites (maybe in parallel, even though they are async internally?) so this might factor in. As Meck is modifying the global module namespace, you should not mock the same module in parallel from different test cases.

I'd suggest trying to use the Meck wrapper [Mock](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) for Elixir to see if this gives you the same result.

Comment: thaks a log! There was 2 things I have to do. At first, ensure mocking only a specific method like `:meck.new(Baz, [:passthrough])`. And the second, as you said, `:meck.unload` to teardown mock.